# view data only for specified registered id in laravel-8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Here I have two tables in my database named user and products
here is user.php

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
            $table->text('profile_photo_path')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

using this table I can register and login by email address. after login it takes me to a page called index.blade.php where I have a button called add data after clicking it, it takes me to my create.blade.php page where I can register some data for the products table. after registered data, those data show me in index.blade.php. That's nice again I can add data and it shows in the index. there is no problem. But the problem is when I login from the index and registered again with a new email address and login with the new email address it's showing me old data I have added with my previous email. but I don't want to see old data after login with new email address.
here is my product.php table

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('detail');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('logo');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

here is my ProductController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
        $products = Product::latest()->paginate(1);

        return view('products.index',compact('products'))

            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
        }
    }
    public function create()
    {
        return view('products.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'detail' => 'required',
            'color' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:640dp*480dp',
            'logo' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:512*512',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
            $destinationPath = 'image/';
            $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
            $input['image'] = "$profileImage";
        }

        if ($logo = $request->file('logo')) {
            $destinationPath = 'logo/';
            $profileLogo = date('YmdHis') . "." . $logo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $logo->move($destinationPath, $profileLogo);
            $input['logo'] = "$profileLogo";
        }

        Product::create($input);

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product created successfully.');
    }
    public function show(Product $product)
    {
        return view('products.show',compact('product'));
    }
    public function edit(Product $product)
    {
        return view('products.edit',compact('product'));
    }
    public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'detail' => 'required',
            'color' => 'required'
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
            $destinationPath = 'image/';
            $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
            $input['image'] = "$profileImage";
        }else{
            unset($input['image']);
        }

        if ($logo = $request->file('logo')) {
            $destinationPath = 'logo/';
            $profileLogo = date('YmdHis') . "." . $logo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $logo->move($destinationPath, $profileLogo);
            $input['logo'] = "$profileLogo";
        }else{
            unset($input['logo']);
        }

        $product->update($input);

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
    }
    public function destroy(Product $product)
    {
        $product->delete();

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
    }

    function indextwo(){
        //return DB::select("select * from  products");
       //DB::table('products')->orderBy('id','desc')->first();
       return Product::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
    }

}
```

here is Product.php as model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'detail', 'image','color','logo'
    ];
}
```

this is index.blade.php

```
@extends('products.layout')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <!-- Authentication -->
               <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}" style="margin: 20px">
                   @csrf

                   <x-jet-dropdown-link href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                           onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                   this.closest('form').submit();">
                       {{ __('Log Out') }}
                   </x-jet-dropdown-link>
               </form>
           </div>
        {{--  --}}
        <div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Click Button</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('products.create') }}"> For New Data</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>App Name</th>
            <th>App Logo</th>
            <th>Splash Image</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th width="280px">Action</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($products as $product)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
            <td><img src="/logo/{{ $product->logo }}" width="100px"></td>
            <td><img src="/image/{{ $product->image }}" width="100px"></td>

            <td>{{ $product->detail }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->color }}</td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('products.destroy',$product->id)}}" method="POST">

                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('products.show',$product->id) }}">Show</a>

                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('products.edit',$product->id) }}">Edit</a>

                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="products_link">Get Json</a>

                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>

    {!! $products->links() !!}

@endsection
```

and this is create.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    {{-- <title>Document</title> --}}

    <title>Bootstrap Colorpicker Example - nicesnippets.com</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.1/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.1/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
@extends('products.layout')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <h2>Add New Data</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('products.index') }}"> Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

<form action="{{ route('products.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Name:</strong>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Detail:</strong>
                <textarea class="form-control" style="height:150px" name="detail" placeholder="Detail"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <strong>Color picker</strong>
            <div id="cp2" class="input-group colorpicker colorpicker-component">
              <input type="text" value="#00AABB" class="form-control" name="color" placeholder="Color" />
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Logo:</strong>
                <input type="file" name="logo" class="form-control" placeholder="logo">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Image:</strong>
                <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" placeholder="image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.colorpicker').colorpicker({});
  </script>
@endsection
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are the products user specific? If so you will need to add the connection between products and users. Because otherwise your controller will always get the latest product, not depending on the user

Comment: How can I add a connection between products and users though I am new in laravel i don't know how to do it

Comment: @AbdullahAlShahed add a user_id column in the products table, and while saving the product data use user id from auth function and insert it in the products table

Comment: This has less to do with laravel and more with DB management, you wil have to add a foreign key on the products table. 
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by ```` Auth::id()